# How to find out dependencies between hash files and modules in the product build?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a large `angular 6` project that have very `modules`.

when I get `prod build` , some of `hash files` has very large size (e.g: 2.7 Mb or more).

how to find out that generate `hash file` Belongs to which module?

e.g:

> 1.14740d297f4ae812ec17.js ===>  people.module.ts
>
> 2.16ab3d967be5798968ad.js ===>  foo.module.ts

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add

```
--namedChunks
```

to your build syntax.
Somthing like :

```
ng build --base-href /ProjectName/ --prod --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk --namedChunks
```

Angular automatically rename chunks to their module name.

this reference might help : 
[Angular Build](https://angular.io/cli/build)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [source-map-explorer](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#inspect-the-bundles) can help you. It analyzes the source map generated with the bundle and draws a map of all dependencies, showing exactly which classes are included in the bundle.